Expo router deep dynamic navigation is not working as expected
I have a problem with deep navigation using expo router. The attached screenshot shows my folder structure.
Folder Structure
The problem is that:
I can navigate from path: /(tabs)/(movies)/[movieId] to  path: /(tabs)/(movies)/(person)/[personId].
But from path: /(tabs)/(movies)/(person)/[personId] I can't navigate to this path: /(tabs)/(movies)/[movieId].
If I try to do that, it navigates me to path: /(tabs)/(movies)/(person)/[personId].
In both cases I'm using same component:
export default function VerticalCard({ data }: ListItem) {
  return (
      <Pressable style={styles.itemContainer} onPress={() => router.push(`/(tabs)/(movies)/${data.id}`)}>
        ...
      </Pressable>
  );
}

Is there a way to solve this routing?
I'm using:
"dependencies": { 
    "expo": "~52.0.11", 
    "expo-router": "~4.0.9", 
    "react": "18.3.1",
    ...
  },

The same is when I'm trying it by using:
<Link href={`/(tabs)/(movies)/${data.id}`} asChild>
  <Pressable style={styles.itemContainer}>
    ...
  </Pressable>
</Link>


Depending of where your page is located in this structure, that is looking for the directory or files, in will always be different unless from the same page. You have not shown a full structure of how things are stored. Try using ./ or ../ but without more info its hard to work out

Full structure is shown on the screenshot and ./  or ../ is not supported in expo router.

Solution 1:
Instead of using
router.push(`/(tabs)/(movies)/${data.id}`)

use
router.push(`//(tabs)/(movies)/${data.id}`)

Solution 2:
Use absolute path navigation with router.replace():
export default function VerticalCard({ data }: ListItem) {
  return (
    <Pressable 
      style={styles.itemContainer} 
      onPress={() => router.replace(`/(tabs)/(movies)/${data.id}`)}
    >
      ...
    </Pressable>
  );
}


Unfortunately, both solutions do not work. Solution 1: Launches a browser application. Solution 2: Keeps the same behavior as a simple push and does not save the stack. But thanks for your help!
